# d3.js Bubble Force Chart application

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bubble-chart

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/146/

I'm developing a bubble chart application that is a derivative of a force chart to provide a little bit of movement.

Here is some of the code. As I create the svg - I also set up the viewBox - which I think could be used to adjust the size of the chart - but I've not been able to adjust the ratios properly to get the correct scaling.

I've also added here the code that adds the nodes - as the node size is calculated - its using a scale variable to affect the size of the orbs.

```
                                 var svg = d3.select(selector)
                            .append("svg")
                                .attr("class", "bubblechart")
                                .attr("width", parseInt(w + margin.left + margin.right,10))
                                .attr("height", parseInt(h + margin.top + margin.bottom,10))
                                .attr('viewBox', "0 0 "+parseInt(w + margin.left + margin.right,10)+" "+parseInt(h + margin.top + margin.bottom,10))
                                .attr('perserveAspectRatio', "xMinYMid")
                            .append("g")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");

                            methods.force = d3.layout.force()
                              .charge(1000)
                              .gravity(100)
                              .size([methods.width, methods.height])


                            var bubbleholder = svg.append("g")
                                    .attr("class", "bubbleholder")


                            var bubbles = bubbleholder.append("g")
                                    .attr("class", "bubbles")

                            var labelbubble = bubbleholder.append("g")
                                    .attr("class", "labelbubble")






                        // Enter
                        nodes.enter()
                            .append("circle")
                             .attr("class", "node")
                              .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                              .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
                              .attr("r", 1)
                              .style("fill", function (d) { return methods.fill(d.label); })
                              .call(methods.force.drag);

                        // Update
                        nodes
                            .transition()
                            .delay(300)
                            .duration(1000)
                              .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius*scale; })

                        // Exit
                        nodes.exit()
                            .transition()
                            .duration(250)
                            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
                            .attr("r", 1)
                            .remove();
```

I have the remaining issues

1. scaling is an issue

I've set the width/heights via data attributes - currently I have a scaling variable set to adjust the size of the orbs depending on the width of the chart. I would like to find a more scientific way of ensuring the chart is resized accordingly and also that the elements always remain central (don't become obscured).

[image]

2. ensuring the smaller elements are on top of the big elements 
   I've also noticed that small objects may randomly fall underneath larger orbs, is there a way to organize the rendering of the orbs dependant on size, so bigger elements always sit at the bottom layer.
   [image]

Comment: Have you looked into [gravity](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout)? You can use gravity to both repel and attract certain elements.

Comment: Hi Lux, I've set gravity in with the force setup -  d3.layout.force()         .charge(1000)         .gravity(100)

Comment: I totally missed that! Sorry, I see it now.

Comment: I've resolved the 2nd issue - by sorting the data at the point it generates the json for the bubble chart - sorting the data values - http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/149/

Comment: Currently, d3 operates in such a manner that elements are drawn in the order they are specified (seems obvious). You can read [mbostock's answer to #2 here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/252). (I know you resolved the issue, but I figured you might want to read up on why that can be a problem)

Comment: How would I solve the problem with the scale though?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the second problem by sorting the data via value.

http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/149/

```
data = data.sort(function(a, b) {return b.value - a.value})
```

Currently I have a scale variable depending on the width of the chart - var scale = methods.width*.005;

but its not very scientific per say

If the chart is 150 width
http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/150/

the chart renders - but the bubbles no longer fit in the space.

the chart at 250 px
http://jsfiddle.net/pPMqQ/151/

Comment: Any suggestions on this - to configure the scale of the orbs correctly and have more control on their positions?